# Retrieve response from SQL after Inserting Data into the Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using PHP to add data from my CRM to an SQL database. When I add the data to the database, I want it to return the ID of the record created in the database back to the CRM. If I can get the response, I can send the details back to the CRM, I just need to know how to get the Record ID when the Record is created. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
require_once("LoginCon.php");

  $potentialDetails = $_POST["potentialDetails"];
  $PotentialID = $_POST["PotentialID"];
  $addressDetails = $_POST["addressDetails"];
  $dateDetails = $_POST["dateDetails"];
  $Photographer = $_POST["Photographer"];
  $Drone = $_POST["Drone"];
  $PhotoEditor = $_POST["PhotoEditor"];
  $VideoEditor = $_POST["VideoEditor"];
  $Videographer = $_POST["Videographer"];
  $VideoEditorNotes = $_POST["VideoEditorNotes"];
  $PhotoEditorNotes = $_POST["PhotoEditorNotes"];
  $ListingDescription = $_POST["ListingDescription"];
  $PhotographerID = $_POST["PhotographerID"];
  $PhotoEditorID = $_POST["PhotoEditorID"];
  $DroneFlyerID = $_POST["DroneFlyerID"];
  $VideographerID = $_POST["VideographerID"];
  $VideoEditorID = $_POST["VideoEditorID"];


$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO PhotoshootsList (potentialDetails, addressDetails, dateDetails, PotentialID, Photographer, Drone, PhotoEditor, VideoEditor, Videographer, VideoEditorNotes, PhotoEditorNotes, ListingDescription, PhotographerID, PhotoEditorID, DroneFlyerID, VideographerID, VideoEditorID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssssssssssssssss", $potentialDetails, $addressDetails, $dateDetails, $PotentialID, $Photographer, $Drone, $PhotoEditor, $VideoEditor, $Videographer, $VideoEditorNotes, $PhotoEditorNotes, $ListingDescription, $PhotographerID, $PhotoEditorID, $DroneFlyerID, $VideographerID, $VideoEditorID);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);


    $response = array();

    $response["success"] = true;  





    echo json_encode($response);


?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_insert_id` ?
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: does your table have an auto-generated unique key, if so the advice in the previous comment should work

Comment: Yup. Maximus2012s answer worked for me. Thanks a bunch!